# Show that the complement of every connected subset of $S^1$ is also connected.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that the complement of every connected subset of $S^1$ is also connected.

Here $S^1$ means $S^1 = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$.

Can someone give some hints on this? It seems that arcs are the only connected subset of $S^1$. If it is true, the the complement of this subset is also a arc, which of course is also connected. Is this intuition true? Can someone give some hints on how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recall what are the connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and use stereographic projection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the map from the open interval (0,1) to the circle
$$
t\mapsto e^{2\pi i(t+t_0)}
$$
This is a homeomorphism onto the image. The image is the circle minus the one point $e^{2\pi t_0}$. So you can pick $t_0$ to make the image include your connected set (unless it's the whole circle, in which case the problem is trivial). Now the problem is reduced to showing that any connected subset of the open interval is an interval, and thinking about how adding that missing point back in connects the complement.